# Spring load time weaving not detecting class annotated with @configurable

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I'm having trouble getting AspectJ to perform load  time weaving on a class annotated with @configurable in my main project. No fields get set and none of the setters are touched.

I don't think there's trouble with the configuration itself, because I've extracted the configuration and tested it on a smaller sandbox project. Just for the sake of it, I'll include it in this question though.

So, I'm wondering:

1. Is there anything in the larger project that might be hindering Spring/AspectJ from detecting the this particular class?
2. Is there any way of checking if spring is even aware of the class in questions?

And lastly, whatever code I can extract (please excuse the obfuscation):

From configuration XML:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:spring-configured />
<context:component-scan base-package="se.isydev" />
<context:component-scan base-package="se.istools" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:settings.properties" />
(...)
<bean class="com.company.ClassToBeWeaved"
    scope="prototype">      
    <property name="injectedBean" ref="injectedBean" />
</bean>
```

And the class itself:

```
@Configurable
public class ClassToBeWeaved {
    private InjectedBean injectedBean;

    @Required
    public void setInjectedBean() { ... }
}
```

**Edit:**

Well, turns out that it wasn't working due to a circular dependency. Oh deary me, I love working on legacy code. Still, my original questions remain.

Comment: What environment are you running this one? LTW only works on certain app servers.

Comment: I ran my sandbox right in eclipse and the proper app is in a WAR running on JBoss

Comment: What version of JBoss are you running and what is the java startup command-line for it? If JBoss is 5.x or higher your don't need a specific agent (and that is a difference with your sandbox, where you have to specify the agent).

Answer (score 0):

You possibly have forgotten to "[weave](http://file:///C:/spring/spring-framework-2.5.6.SEC01/docs/reference/html_single/index.html#aop-aj-ltw)". Add `-javaagent:path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` or  `-javaagent:path/to/spring-agent.jar` to your comman line.

I also suggest that you `@Autowire` your dependency rather than explicitly inject it.

Comment: Nope, not that either. -javaagent:(...)/spring-agent-2.5.6.jar" is on my command line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the LTW requires a META-INF/aop.xml on your classpath.  It should look like:

```
<aspectj>
    <!--
        Uncomment this is you need AOP logging <weaver options="-verbose
        -showWeaveInfo
        -XmessageHandlerClass:org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJWeaverMessageHandler">
    -->
    <weaver>
        <include within="com.xxx.MyClass" />
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect"/>
        <include within="org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Comment: Ah nope, doesn't require it. As I said, it works dandy in my sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more then 1 spring XML file? I believe I had a problem <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
 was not in the 'most parent' of my XML files.

Comment: See my edit. The error was due to a circular dependency in the code (not mine).

Answer (score 0):

Some hints for your question.

To make load time weaving work with Spring, not only you need to configure properly the **aop.xml** but you need ALSO to have the **spring-instrument.jar** & **spring-aspects.jar**.

These jar files contain their own **aop.xml** that declare Spring aspects to handle:

- *@Transactional* support
- *@Configurable* support
- JPA Exception translation support
- *@Async* annotation for scheduling support

**What happen in the background ?**

When using AspectJ load-time weaving, the *@Transactional* and *@Configurable* implementations are no longer based on **JDK proxies** or **CGLIB proxies** but real AspectJ **aspects**.

To enable these real aspects, you need the additional jar files. The jar also contain declaration of these aspects in their own aop.xml

More details on how to integrate Spring with AspectJ [here](http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/01/01/advanced-aspectj-part-v-integration-with-spring/)